# stl functor with more than 2 arguments

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I am working with STL but I don't have c++0x and I can't use boost, I wonder if there is anyway to bind 2 or more arguments to the functor when use std::generate? Something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

float f(int x, float y, float z) {return x*(y+z);}

int main(void)
{
  std:vector<int> v(100);
  float x=1.2, y=-3.3;
  generate(v.begin(), v.end(), bind3argu(f, _, x, y)); // something like this: '_' is from vector

  // as suggested, I also try
  generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(f, x, y));
  return 0;
}
```

I try to use std::bind but it doesn't compile with g++ 4.4.6. BTW, does std::bind being supported in c++0x and/or c++11 only?

Comment: `main` is required to have an `int` return type.

Comment: What is that `_` part coming from vector ? Is that the initial value that the vector elements may contain ?

Comment: hi Mahesh, the code I post doesn't not exist, I just want to show the idea that I want to implement. _ stands for elements of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use functors, try using `std::transform`.

```
float foo(float z) {
    float x=1.2, y=-3.3;
    return x*(y+z);
}

std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), foo);
```

The real problem how to pass vector value as well. Had if not the case, `std::bind` would be useful.

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(f, x, y /*Any number of varaibales*/));
```

Comment: thx, but what happen if x and y are constant variable, i.e. if might be changed from time to time and need to be fed as arguments

Comment: See the update. You can use `std::bind` as long as you don't want to use vector element's initial value.

Comment: Thanks. I try to use std::bind as in the code updated in the question. But it doesn't compile. Am I missing anything? Thanks

Comment: `f` takes 3 parameters but you are passing only 2 (i.e., x,y).

Comment: yes, that's what I am asking. since the first parameter should be the element of the vector, how do I pass it to the function? If it is c++11, I can use _1 and something like that to do so. But my compiler doesn't support c++11 nor c++0x

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write your own functor to do whatever you want.

For example: (untested code, may need pointers instead of references)

```
struct Three {
    Three ( float &x, float &y ) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
    float operator ( float z ) const { /* do something with x_,y_ and z */ }
private:
    float &x_;
    float &y_;
};
```

and then you can say:

```
float x=1.2, y=-3.3;
Three three ( x, y );
generate( v.begin(), v.end(), three );
```

The advantage of bind1st, or boost::bind, or C++11 lambdas is that you can just write the code you want w/o all the scaffolding of defining a structure.